# Comparing two tables in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've two tables which are identical in structure, they have a key, a timestamp, a value and a foreign key.

I would like to list all the records from the second table which don't have a matching record in the first with the same timestamp, value and foreign key?

How would I go about this?

Comment: The answer depends on the **exact table definition**, which you must include with such a question. Use `\d tbl` in `psql`. Possible NULL values must be considered. Also, your version of Postgres, please.

Answer (score 0):

Two approaches you can try, first using "exists":

```
select a.key,
       a.ts,
       a.value
from a
where not exists (select 1
                  from b
                  where a.key = b.key
                    and (a.ts != b.ts
                         or a.value != b.value
                         or a.fk != b.fk))
;
```

And using "in":

```
select a.key,
       a.ts,
       a.value
from a
where (a.key, a.ts, a.value) not in (select b.key, b.ts, b.value from b)
;
```

Edit: I realized you've got four columns and are likely matching on the key. I modified the "exists" query to reflect that - that query now checks for a match on the key between the tables and then checks if any of the other three columns differ.